# Get value from xml element attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The task I need to accomplish is to get the value of the element attribute (ws:PriorValue="PriorValue) and map it to a field in a C# class. The way I have it now I get null.
I don't work much with XML and have never used XSLT before but from what I've seen I would need to use <xsl:value-of select="" /> but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that with the what we already have. I was able to map the value of the element (TestValue) using
<xsl:with-param name="targetNode" select="ws:Additional_Information/ws:User_Name/[@Pws:PriorValue] so I know that works but obviously it's not the correct value.

Example XML

```
<ws:Additional_Information>
    <ws:User_Name ws:PriorValue="PriorValue">TestValue</ws:User_Name>
<ws:Additional_Information>
```

XSLT Template:

```
<xsl:template name="MapElement">
    <xsl:param name="targetNode" />
    <xsl:param name="elementName" />
    <xsl:if test="$targetNode and string-length($targetNode/text())>0">
      <xsl:element name="{$elementName}" >
        <xsl:value-of select="$targetNode/text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

Map value to C#:

```
<xsl:template name="MapWorker" match="ws:Worker" mode="TransformWorker">
    <Worker>
        <AdditionaInformation>
            <xsl:call-template name="MapElement">
                <xsl:with-param name="targetNode" select="ws:Additional_Information/ws:User_Name/@ws:PriorValue" />
                <xsl:with-param name="elementName" select="'PriorUserName'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="MapElement">
                <xsl:with-param name="targetNode" select="ws:Personal/ws:Name_Data[ws:Name_Type='Legal']/ws:Last_Name" />
                <xsl:with-param name="elementName" select="'LastName'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="MapElement">
                <xsl:with-param name="targetNode" select="ws:Personal/ws:Name_Data[ws:Name_Type='Preferred']/ws:First_Name" />
                <xsl:with-param name="elementName" select="'PreferredFirstName'" />
           </xsl:call-template>
       </AdditionalInformation>
   </Worker>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/text()` from your XPath expressions, because attributes have no `text()` children (because they are already an attribute child that cannot have any children itself) - hence the attempt to get the `text()` of an attribute will be `null`.
Changing your template to the following will handle both elements and attributes:

```
<xsl:template name="MapElement">
    <xsl:param name="targetNode" />
    <xsl:param name="elementName" />
    <xsl:if test="$targetNode and string-length($targetNode)>0">
      <xsl:element name="{$elementName}" ><xsl:value-of select="$targetNode"/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```